# RollingFileAppender configuring through Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

My log needs to have maxsize 5KB, no backup files and needs to append. When the log reach 5KB it erase the amount of data necessary to fit the new data.
For example:

1: a b c d

2: b c d e

3: c d e f

```
     Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
     rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);    
     PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n");
     rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(layout));
     RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, "test.log");
     fileAppender.setAppend(true);
     fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("5KB");
     fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(0);
```

My problem is when the size reach 5KB. It doesn't append (roll) like I want, its overwrite the hole data. Why it doesn't append? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how the RollingFileAppender works.
Javadoc: 
*RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when they reach a certain size.*

So it rolls over a number of files and not the lines/content in one file.

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any lib that does what I want?

Comment: I don't know such an implementation, sry. Maybe you have to do such a "Paging"FileAppender implementation by yourself.

Comment: Just to clarify a wee bit, it rolls over when the log file reaches a certain size, as many times as the #of rollovers is configured to be (e.g. 5).  Each rollover file is suffixed with the rollover # e.g. myLogFile.log.1, myLogFile.log.2, myLogFile.log.3, myLogFile.log.4, myLogFile.log.5....   The latest will just be named myLogFile.log

Answer (score 0):

Just switch property `append = false`. It will work.